# How input all params from console without interactively?

Tags: start-up, term, command-line-arguments

Here snippet of my elips function:

```
(defun log-report (filePath uniqueText)
  "Create log4j record report from any log4j (e.g.traceXXX.log) files. Log4j level MUST be in square brackets. e.g.: [DEBUG] Any text"
  (interactive "sPlease, input full path to log4j file: \nsUnique text: ")
  (message "\n\n\n\nInput path is %s" filePath)
  (if (file-exists-p filePath)
      (progn
    (if (file-exists-p FINAL_REPORT_PATH)
```

I start terminal. Input **2 params** and my function **log-report** start.
Nice

Here result:
[image]

But I want to pass all parameters immediately.

Something like this:

```
emacs --script log-report.el -f log-report "some_log_file" "some_find_text"
```

Without Emacs ask me about input params.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you introduce an option `--mylog` with the two required arguments.

You write a function `my-log-file` that processes the command line arguments after `--mylog` and register it in `command-line-functions`.

The function `my-log-file` checks `argi` whether it currently processes the option `--mylog` and moves the two required arguments from `command-line-args-left` to `my-log-options`. (You can implement whatever you want here.)

Demo script `test.el`:

```el
(defvar my-log-options nil
  "Required command line args of --mylog read by `my-log-file-handler'.")

(defun my-log-file-handler ()
  "Move the required args of --mylog to `my-log-options'.
You can also start logging here if you want.
Logging code is not included yet."
  (when (string-match "-mylog" argi)
    (when (< (length command-line-args-left) 2)
      (user-error "Expect three arguments after --mylog"))
    (setq my-log-options
      (list (nth 0 command-line-args-left)
        (nth 1 command-line-args-left))
      command-line-args-left
      (nthcdr 2 command-line-args-left))
    t))

(add-to-list 'command-line-functions #'my-log-file-handler)

(defun show-my-log-options ()
  "Demonstrate that \"-f\" invokes `show-my-log-options' after
   all command line options are processed."
  (message "Showing my-log-options: %s" my-log-options))
```

If you call emacs with

```
emacs --script test.el --mylog one two -f show-my-log-options
```

you get the output

```
Showing my-log-options: (one two)
```